# Identity of a supposed anonymous referee revealed through "Description" of the report

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors, acknowledgement, journal-workflow

I received a referee report from a journal (with single blind peer review policy).

If that matters, the journal uses "Editorial Manager" system.

By clicking on "View Attachments", one can see 5 these information "Action", "Uploaded By", "Description", "File Name", "File Size".

The content of the column "Uploaded By" is "Editor".

The content of the column "Description" is  "from prof. X"

Hence the identity of the referee is disclosed.

I am wondering if it is an unintended mistake from the Editor or it is the referee who has written such description.

The referee has done a substantial work to evaluate the manuscript and has proposed many suggestions leading to the improvement of the manuscript.

My dilemma is that, as I know the identity of the referee, should I use his real name in the acknowledgement or just thank an anonymous referee?

Answer (score 49):

If the review itself is not signed, it sounds like the unblinding was not deliberate. I would:

- Reply as if the review were anonymous
- Notify the editor in a separate, private message saying there may have been an error in showing the reviewer name

Comment: Agree. To do otherwise might suggest to others that you were given some special treatment.

Comment: I would add: **Notify the Editor after the paper is published.** Otherwise you risk some complications. You did not do anything wrong (especially, you did not actively search for who the referee was), and the editor could over-react in some way and even blame you or change his attitude towards you.

Comment: @yo' Hide the truth until it's too late! Bury the evidence! Learn these and other useful techniques in our new course _Shady Ethics 101_.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nothing shady. The authors did not do anything wrong. If it's a mistake, it's a mistake of either the Editor, the reviewer or the system they work in. I don't see _any_ reason why the authors should risk their article being badly treated by anyone involved.

Comment: @yo' If you are aware of something which you think might negatively affect the chances of your paper being accepted, not bringing that up is shady. It doesn't matter whose fault it is. (IMO, this shouldn't actually affect your chances. The worry about non-anonymous reviews is that the reviewer might seek favours by giving a good review. But, in this case, the referee thought s/he was anonymous, so wouldn't have been trying anything.)

Comment: @yo' If the editor will give you a hard time about accidentally seeing the unblinded names before publication, it's likely they'll be even harder on you if they find you deliberately & strategically held back the information until after publication. Sure, they probably won't rescind publication (though they might if they feel the review process was tainted), but you just burned bridges with them, and will find it hard to publish with that editor/journal in the future. -- If you're looking long term (and not just for this particular paper) the best course of action is to be open and forthright.

Comment: @R.M., it's possible you missed in the original comment that the author was recommended to immediately tell the editor about the unblinding. So there's no withholding of information.

Comment: @CameronBrick But RM is directly responding to a comment that explicitly recommends withholding!

Comment: My mistake, apologies

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I agree that the best and most responsible thing to do is to notify the editor immediately, and that no reasonable editor should let that affect their decision. That said, people aren't always reasonable, and you should be prepared for the (small) chance that the response is "OMG you hacked our site! We'll sue you and blacklist you from all our journals!" (Worse, with some of the anti-hacking laws in place in various jurisdictions, they might actually have a non-zero chance of winning the lawsuit if they argue that you weren't authorized to click the "View Attachments" button.)

Comment: ... That said, even factoring in the small risk of an extreme overreaction, I agree with @R.M.'s point that waiting doesn't make the risk any lesser. If you're going to disclose this issue at all (and I agree that you probably should), it's best to do it immediately.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It seems that the most prudent course of action would be to explicitly ask the editor for permission to click each button and then report anomalies soon after permission is granted, but not before.  If something is not needed for the OP's process, then permission should not be requested until after the process is complete - but perhaps OP would have lost interest by then.  OP should not click on any buttons that the editor has not explicitly granted permission for.

Comment: @R.M. in general if people are not willing to take constructive feedback well, it is OK to burn bridges.

Comment: @DavidRicherby IMO "If you are aware of something which you think might negatively affect the chances of your paper being accepted, not bringing that up is shady" goes too far. For example, I don't suppose anyone would argue that if you should inform the editor if you happen to be a member of some demographic you know they are biased against. I wouldn't feel ethically required to disclose information if it would be unethical for the journal to allow that information to affect its decision. And I think this case clearly falls into that category.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime If you believe that a journal is unethical (e.g., by racially discriminating among people who submit papers), you shouldn't support that journal by sending your papers there.

Comment: @R.M.: I don't understand how it might possibly be strategic to hold back the disclosure until after publication, can you explain why? (Do you mean OP could figure out based on their identity what changes or citations to use on the resubmission? and even if, how would that be unethical by OP?)

Comment: @smci because it happens too often that if you bring up a security issue, that instead of a "thank you" you get an "omg you hacked the system." reply.

Comment: @PieterB: really? Sounds crazy to me.

Comment: OP did not have a security issue in my opinion.

Answer (score 23):

I would ignore the inadvertent disclosure of the referee's name.  It is unimportant.  Do not name the referee in your manuscript.

Comment: Could you explain more about why the disclosure of the referee's name is not important? It seems like journals put a lot of effort into the single-blind peer review process. That makes it seem important.

Comment: @BrianMoths it is important that authors do not bribe reviewers.  That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 6):

Ask the editor.

Probably it is a mistake, but it is not your fault. I do not expect this to be to your detriment (and they might already have noticed it themself) and you seem to have a dilemma what to do.